# incorrect value returned when using the max function

Tags: python, python-3.x, max

The following code returns an incorrect max value:

```
maximum = 0
f =open("data.dat", "r")

for line in f:
    global maximum
    fields = line.split()
    classcode = fields[0]
    name = fields[1]
    scr = fields[2]

    maximum=max(scr)
    print(classcode, name, scr)

f.close()
print("maximum=", maximum)
```

The data file is

```
1 test2 100
1 test1 100
1 test3 20
1 test4 60
1 test5 33
```

And the result I get is

```
1 test2 100
1 test1 100
1 test3 20
1 test4 60
1 test5 33
maximum= 3
```

Any idea why I get the wrong value would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying `max()` to *each individual value*; `max()` has nothing to compare that one value with. In fact, it finds the one *character with the highest value* out of `scr`, which is just a string (a sequence of characters). Of your last `scr` value, the string `'33'`, both characters have equal value so it picked one, `'3'`.

It'd be more efficient to collect the values in a list (after converting to integers first), then calling `max()` on that list. Then it has something to compare with:

```
scores = []

for line in f:
    fields = line.split()
    classcode = fields[0]
    name = fields[1]
    scr = int(fields[2])
    scores.append(scr)
    print(classcode, name, scr)

maximum = max(scores)
print("maximum=", maximum)
```

Comment: I think you're missing a `scores.append(scr)` line in the loop.

Comment: @Blckknght: *facepalm*

Answer (score 1):

The line `maximum=max(scr)` doesn't do what you think it does. It's comparing the values of the characters in the string `scr`.

What I think you want instead is `maximum = max(int(scr), maximum)`. This picks the larger of the current value or the old maximum, and works on integers rather than strings.

Comment: Cheers folks that was extremely helpful.